# Store Game Statistics from Android App

Tags: android, database, sqlite, statistics, storage

I've got some **basic Java** experience and **very basic Android app development experience** (currently reading Android Wireless Application Development Volume I).

I'm trying to develop an android app to **keep track of Beer Pong statistics** (shooting percentage, win percentage, shooting streak, etc.).  I want to be able to store this data so that I can display leaderboards within the app and also transfer the data to my computer for more complex statistical analysis and permanent tracking.

I'd appreciate some input on the best/easiest way to do this regarding...

1)  **What information to store?**
I imagine I'd need to store user/player names and keep track of every single shot make/miss?  What sort of **format** would be effective?

2)  **When to store it?**
Should I "commit" these makes/misses to storage after each shot?  Or at the end of the game?  I would like to implement a 'back' or 'undo' button to account for mistakes.  How would this affect when I should store the data?

3)  **How to store it?**
Based on my limited android app development experience, would SQLite databases be easy to learn and appropriate?  Would storing to a google excel doc be easy (requires constant internet connection, though)?  Would some other form of storage be better?

Thank you and OSS!

Comment: All valid comments so far.  I can't upvote apparently because I'm new.

I will mess around with SQLite a little bit and see what I can do.

Comment: Just remember that even if you can't upvote yet, you're still able to select the best answer. It keeps your answer acceptance high, which makes people more likely to answer your questions in the future. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SQL database would be your best bet, and committing changes to the database on the fly is fine.

undo / redo is implemented best using the Command Object design pattern. The command objects can store the information needed to back out a transaction from your data source for the user action they are associated with. Simply push new command objects onto the stack each time the user performs actions (storing details of their action in the command object), and then pop those command objects off the stack and call their revert method when the user hits undo. The revert method uses the stored data from when you created the object to back out the transaction from your SQL database.

[Wiki Link for Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is very good for device storage so I think that would be the best.

I learned my SQLite from thenewboston.com and have an example of it - github.com/jordanbtahabsim/Family-Tree

Answer (score 0):

I think an SQLite database is your best option for storage. 2nd best but simpler option would be to just store the information in user setting.  If I where you I would work somewhat backward from the data.  I would create the table in sqlite and start writing interesting queries against the database.  There are good tools to read the content of the database etc.  So I would spend some time with SQLite outside android. Then wrap your access inside a content provider when you pull it into android.

Answer (score 0):

1) Depending on what sort of statistics you plan on running,there are a number of things you may want to keep track of: Which cups were hit, their position at the time they were hit, number and position of cups for for each shot, whether the shot was bounced, etc.

2) Committing at the end of the game seems like it would allow you to condense the amount of information stored, as well as give you better options for mistake corrections.

3) As others have said, SQLite seems like it would be a good choice for data storage, and shouldn't be too hard to pick up on.